# URLGeneration Error in WebSphere Portal

Tags: websphere-portal

We're using WebSphere Portal ver 7. In our themes we've a flyout menu in the header. The links in the flyout menu vary based on the type of the user accessing the application. 
The links are rendered using the portal navigation tags -

```
<portal:urlGeneration contentNode="com.XXXXX.member.XX.XXX123" keepNavigationalState="false">
```

The access to the `contentNode` is set on visibility rules. For users that do not have access to a particular content node the link is not visible.

Since the flyout menu is in the themes header, whenever a logged in user does not have access to a particular link in the menu the portal navigation throws `URLGeneration` errors resulting in `NullPointer` exceptions. These errors get logged into our SysOut. The frequency of errors gets so high that the logs roll back and it gets hard for the server team to maintain them.

Since this a WebSphere portal issue there is a fix available for it in Portal 8 onwards but not in Portal 7.

We would like to know if there could be a way the application could handle the `URLGeneration` errors gracefully and stop from filling our logs. We do not want to implement the same visibility rule checks in our themes because then we would lose the whole purpose of using the portal navigation and also when Business Rules change it would be another add on item to be changed.

Would like to hear some inputs.

PS - PFB error log stack trace -

```
[10/13/16 17:03:16:097 EDT] 00000052 CreateUrlComm E com.ibm.wps.util.CreateUrlCommand execute EJPEJ0012E: Could not find the node ID and root ID corresponding to the given content node ID.
[10/13/16 17:03:16:099 EDT] 00000052 UrlGeneration E com.ibm.wps.engine.tags.UrlGenerationTag doStartTag EJPEJ0004E: An unexpected exception occurred.
                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.wps.util.CreateUrlCommand.createFriendlyURL(CreateUrlCommand.java:809)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.tags.UrlGenerationTag.doStartTag(UrlGenerationTag.java:344)
    at com.ibm._jsp._header._jspService(_header.java:1678)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:576)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:250)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:970)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell it to ignore, either fatal only or turn it off
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rtrb_enabletrc.html

```
com.ibm.wps.engine.tags.UrlGenerationTag=off
```

or you could put exception handling around the jsp to handle it better

Comment: Turning the logger off is the last option, we tried to explore around but most options were only available in Portal 8. We tried exception handling at the jsp but it seems like the thrown Null Pointer Exception is flowing all the way to jsp hence the try catch blocks are not able to catch it. We're going to try once more  before we finally turn off the logger.